# How can I detect whether my audio stream is: playing, paused or finished?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I'm working on an online radio website and am trying to detect what state the audio player is currently in for the user.

The current setup I've got is often wrong in knowing this and if I'm on iOS and I pause from the lock screen player instead, it will still think it's playing because I never clicked the html pause button.

Finally how is it possible to detect when my stream has fully ended. I've tried: `onstalled=""`, `onwaiting=""`, `onerror=""`, `onended=""`. But none of them work 100% of the time. The closest one to work would be: `onstalled=""`, but even that only had a 60% success rate or so (occasionally when I'm loading the site it would tell me it has ended).

***HTML:***

```
<audio autoplay="" id="player" title="" oncanplay="radioLoaded()">
    <source src="...">
</audio>
```

***Javascript:***

```
function radioLoaded() {
    if (player.paused) {
        document.getElementById('radioplaypause').innerHTML = varRadioResume;
    } else if (player.play) {
        document.getElementById('radioplaypause').innerHTML = varRadioPause;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('radioplaypause').innerHTML = varRadioLoading;
    }

    window.player = document.getElementById('player');
    document.getElementById('radioplaypause').onclick = function () {
        if (player.paused) {
            player.play();
            this.innerHTML = varRadioPause;
        } else {
            player.pause();
            this.innerHTML = varRadioResume;
        }
    }
};

function radioEnded() { 
    document.getElementById('radiolivetext').innerHTML = 'OFFLINE';
    document.getElementById('radioplayer').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('radioinformation').style.display = 'none';
};
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'ended' exactly? Is it just random stops when the audio is buffering due to slow connection or when the user clicks the 'pause/stop' button or something else?

Comment: When my radio is finished for the night. When I'm no longer sending/uploading data to the website.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with some corrections/notes to the code in general:

```
function radioLoaded() {

    // move this line to the top
    window.player = document.getElementById('player'); // !!! <-- name too generic, possibility of global collisions

    var playPauseButton = document.getElementById('radioplaypause');

    if (player.paused) {
        playPauseButton.innerHTML = varRadioResume;
    } else if (player.play) {
        playPauseButton.innerHTML = varRadioPause;
    } else {
        playPauseButton.innerHTML = varRadioLoading;
    }

    playPauseButton.onclick = function () {
        if (player.paused) {
            player.play();
            this.innerHTML = varRadioPause;
        } else {
            player.pause();
            this.innerHTML = varRadioResume;
        }
    };

    player.onended = function () {
        console.log('ended');
    };

    // other helpful events
    player.onpause = function () {
       console.log('paused...');
    }

    player.onplay = function () {
       console.log('playing...');
    }

    player.onprogress = function (e) {
       console.log(e.loaded + ' of ' + e.total + ' loaded');
    }
};
```

Comment: `onended` fires only when the file reached the end on its own, you are talking about `onpause` event. For the progress thing you would have to set some timers with `if`s to track that.

Comment: Yeah, `onended` doesn't seem to work. What would be the next best approach for it to realise the stream has stopped? As I don't think it ever does "end" :(

Comment: I believe radio would involve streaming, let me look if there are any events to account for that.

Comment: Do you think it would be better to just post a separate question specific to that, as I can't find many helpful answers around

Comment: Why not, you can. You also may want to [google stackoverflow](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+streaming+audio+events&safe=off&tbs=qdr:y) first.